# Accessing external files within Java applications under Windows and Linux Operating Systems

Tags: java, linux, netbeans, file-io

Please I am facing the following issue:

Throughout my Java program, i am accessing some files which it seems they are being accessed in a different way under windows compared to Linux. For example, if i wanted to access the following file within the same folder as the project i would write the following:

**Under Linux:** `File Operations_File = new File("Data/Operations.txt");`
**Under Windows:** `File Operations_File = new File("Data\\Operations.txt");`

I will be needing a standard methodology that works under all operating systems (or at least those two). As coding two versions of my code is not elegant at all.

My Two operating system that I am operating on are: Linux Mint 9 and Windows XP. I used NetBeans 6.9.1 throughout all the project.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

File.separator is exactly for this.

File f = new File("Data" + File.separator + "Operations.txt");

Don't get confused with File.pathSeparator, that is used to separate paths from each other.  For example:

/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/var/lib

In the above example, : is the path separator (windows uses ; for path separators).

Comment: Thanks a lot Zeki! Completely understood! It is working perfectly now. Thanks for your time around.

Comment: -1: Using the two-argument constructor as shown in the @ColinD answer is a better way to go in my opinion.  It has less fiddly string manipulation

Comment: If you have nested folders you will still need to use File.separator so I think it's important for people to understand how that works.  I assumed that the original poster was making things more simple than they actually were.

Answer (score 2):

You can also create a `File` representing the directory and another `File` representing something in that directory like this:

```
File dataDir = new File("Data");
File operationsFile = new File(dataDir, "Operations.txt");
```

You could also skip the `File` for the directory and just do this as well:

```
File operationsFile = new File("Data", "Operations.txt");
```

Under Windows, printing out `operationsFile` gives `Data\Operations.txt` as expected.